# "Высуня язык" — форма деепричастия

Tags: фразеология, словоизменение

Как сложилось, что форма деепричастия во фразеологизме ***бежать высуня язык*** такая необычная *(высун**я*** вместо *высун**ув**)?* Или это было нормой, когда выражение сформировалось?

Comment: Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию (§177. Формы деепричастий): В парах **высунув – высуня** (ср.: бежать высуня язык); **положив – положа** (ср.: положа руку на сердце), **разинув – разиня** (ср.: слушать разиня рот), **скрепив – скрепя** (ср.: согласиться скрепя сердце), **сломив– сломя** (ср.: броситься сломя голову), **спустив – спустя** (ср.: работать спустя рукава) и т. п. вторые формы являются устарелыми, но сохраняются в устойчивых фразеологических выражениях. (Ссылка во втором комментарии — тут не "влезает".)

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091256.html#id-40%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%C2%A7177%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это устаревшая форма деепричастия, закрепившаяся только в данном фразеологизме. Кстати, наряду с этой формой в данном обороте активно используется и современная "высунув". Аналогично "разиня рот" - и тоже вытесняется формой "разинув".

Вообще фразеологизмы богаты подобными архаизмами в деепричастиях, связано, видимо, с тем, что деепричастие относительно молодая часть речи.
Вот ещё примеры, похожие на рассматриваемый: ***положа руку на сердце, спустя рукава, сломя голову, скрепя сердце***. Всё это архаичные формы деепричастий, вне фразеологизмов в современном языке не используются.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все эти примеры знакомы, конечно, но сами не вспомнились, а у вас уже готовая подборка. 

Comment: У Розенталя где-то есть более полный список. А мне остается только добавить, что по пободной схеме в современном языке продолжают образовываться формы деепричастий бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида: звеня, летя, ворча и проч.

Comment: *Да, точно!)))*